# How do I write unit-test in python 3.7 for Google client library for BigQuery?

Tags: unit-testing, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-client

I am using the Google Client Library for BigQuery and storage.

Below is the function which I am using for creating a table in BigQuery using query result.

```
def create_bq_table():
    client = bigquery.Client()
    job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(destination="dashboard_filter")
    sql = """
    SELECT *
    FROM `my-rep.my_table.all_filters`
    """
    query_job = client.query(sql, job_config=job_config)
    query_job.result()
```

Now I have to write a unit-test for this by mocking Google Client library. But I am not sure how can I do that. Could somebody please let me know how to proceed?

Comment: Why do you have to write a unit test?  This sounds more like an integration test.  Whatever you do, you probably don't want to run this against any production data when "testing."

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using Python. Don't know if you have finally done your unit test but if not, I would suggest [bq-test-kit](https://github.com/tiboun/python-bq-test-kit). This framework allows you to interact with BigQuery in Python and make tests reliables.

You have 3 ways to inject data into it :

- Create datasets and tables with an ability to isolate their name and therefore have your own namespace
- Rely on temp tables, where data is inserted with data literals
- data literal merged into your query

Hope that this helps.